# how to handle bootstrap dropdown using the cucumber bdd framework in java-selenium

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, cucumber, angular-ui-bootstrap

I built my script in BDD framework. And I tried several method to handle Bootstrap dropdown used in the application I'm testing.

But there is no luck.

How to handle bootstrap dropdown for my application using my framework?

UIAction class File:

I've coded all the UI actions which will be performed commonly and I'm calling this functions method in another class where ever necessary.

So for dropdown I tried with select method I've coded in UIAction, which is as follows.

Select method in UIAction class:

```
public class UIActions  {

public static void select(String UIName, String objTechName, String data) throws Exception{ 
        try{

            Log.info("Selecting item in Combo " + objTechName);
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).sendKeys(data);

            //final Select selectBox = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))));
            final Select selectBox = new Select(driver.findElement(ObjectMap.getLocator(objTechName)));

            //selectBox.selectByValue(data);
            selectBox.selectByVisibleText(data);
         }catch(Exception e){
             Log.error("Not able to Select an item --- " + e.getMessage());
             throw new UserDefinedException("<<< Unable to Select '" + data +  "' in Field '" + UIName + "' >>> "+e.getMessage());           
             //DriverScript.bTestStepResult = false;

            }
        }
}
```

Defined the object in separate class:

```
public class ObjectsDefinition extends UIActions {

    public static final String OBJ_Origin_DROPDOWN = "|xpath|//span[contains(text(),'BRANCH')]";

}
```

Called the method for select function in stepdefinition class file in my framework:

```
public class StepDefinitions extends UIActions {

@And("^User captures Origin (.*)$") 

    public void User_captures_Origin(String arg7) throws Throwable {

        UIActions.select("OBJ_Origin_DROPDOWN", VASTObjectsDefinition.OBJ_Origin_DROPDOWN, arg7);
        //UIActions.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'BRANCH')]"));
        Thread.sleep(50);       
    }
}
```

When the above code not worked, I tried as per the suggestion from 1 of the blog to handle the bootstrap dropdown, But this also didnot worked for me:

```
@And("^User captures Origin (.*)$")
    public void User_captures_Origin(String arg7) throws Exception{

          // this is using action class to set focus on any element
          // below line is just for clicking on perticular dropdownlist

             WebElement ele= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/button"));
        // To count the number of value in drop down

        Actions act= new Actions(driver);

        act.moveToElement(ele).perform();

        // below line xpath is to select the value
       List<WebElement> Dropdownvalues= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'BRANCH')]"));

       int total_links=Dropdownvalues.size();

       System.out.println("Total values count are:"+total_links);


       for(int i=0;i<total_links;i++){

            // To get the name of all links:

            WebElement element=Dropdownvalues.get(i);

           String dropdownvalues_names= element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
    //   boolean status= element.isEnabled();

          // System.out.println("Links name are:"+links_names +"Link status is "+ status);       


           // To clicking on perticular link:

                       if (dropdownvalues_names.equalsIgnoreCase("BRANCH")){

                             element.click();
                            break;


                       }

       }


      //  Actions act= new Actions(driver);

       // act.moveToElement(ele).perform();

      //  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div/select")).click();


      //  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(ele).click().perform();



        Thread.sleep(3000);



          }
```

When I run the script getting the error as below:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 85 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: '0967JNBPBB010L', ip: '10.5.70.125', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_76-ea'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, version=9, platform=WINDOWS, proxy={proxyType=}, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:24652/, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: df6bf10c-51d0-46b3-ab24-95897f29223f
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:326)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at com.org.frameworkFiles.stepDefinitions.StepDefinitions.User_captures_Origin(StepDefinitions.java:173)
    at ?.And User captures Origin BRANCH(1_Create Application.feature:12)
```

Below are the Bootstrap codes writted for the dropdown field in my applicationn:

This part of codes are for clicking the dropdown:

```
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select show-tick">
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn-default" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" data-id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlOrigin" title="Choose Origin Code">
<span class="filter-option pull-left">Choose Origin Code</span>
<span class="bs-caret">
<span class="caret"/>
</span>
</button>
```

This part of codes are for selection of dropdown fields:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox">
<ul class="dropdown-menu inner" aria-expanded="false" role="listbox">
<li data-original-index="0">
<a class="" role="option" data-tokens="null" style="" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
<span class="text">BRANCH</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"/>
</a>
</li>
<li data-original-index="1">
<a class="" role="option" data-tokens="null" style="" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
<span class="text">CALL CENTRE</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"/>
</a>
</li>
<li data-original-index="2">
<a class="" role="option" data-tokens="null" style="" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
<span class="text">INTERNET</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"/>
</a>
</li>
<li data-original-index="3">
<a class="" role="option" data-tokens="null" style="" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
<span class="text">PRIVATE BANKING</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"/>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Again select HTML code was written with same fields but, when i try to higlight with this through firebug nothing was highlighting: The highlight of field was happened only with above part of codes:

```
<select id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlOrigin" class="selectpicker" title="Choose Origin Code" data-max-options="1" multiple="" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlOrigin" tabindex="-98">
<option value="BRH">BRANCH</option>
<option value="CC">CALL CENTRE</option>
<option value="INT">INTERNET</option>
<option value="PB">PRIVATE BANKING</option>
</select>
</div>
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_RequiredFieldValidator8" class="zmdi zmdi-alert-triangle form-control-feedback" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Guessing here -- The HTML select tags are not visible so the code you have written using 'Select' will not work. Your code should interact with the ul and li as they are the visible components.

Comment: @Grasshopper, In my script I tried to interact with ul and li components only, u can check my  xpath - //span[contains(text(),'BRANCH')]. The 1st xpath I copied from firebug for click on that drop-down. But the thing is click itself is not happening when I run my script.

Comment: Have you tried with a simpler css selector instead of long xpaths... In your script you are moving to that element but not clicking. What is the value of the number of links that you are printing out? Which line is line 173?

Comment: @Grasshopper, Yes I tried with CSS selector and also tried xpath with click option as well. But that also didn't work. I'm trying to print the 1st value from drop down. The line 173 refers to element.click() which is in 4th code snippet box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing to click on the drop down button. This is minimal code to select drop down option. Please try and let me know.

```
   @And("^User captures Origin (.*)$")              
   public void User_captures_Origin(String origin) throws Exception{ 

    // click on drop down button
    WebElement DropdownButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-id='ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlOrigin']"));
    DropdownButton.click();

    // select a drop down option
     WebElement DropdownOption= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li/a/span[text()="+origin+"]"));
     DropdownOption.click();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks a lot for your answer. It worked for me. I was using some other solution and which had more lines of code for selecting the drop down values. But the solution which you gave is very minimal lines.